# How do I use ColumnWidth?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm having trouble with explicitly setting a column width.

I've tried the following but keep getting the same error of `Application-defined or object-defined error`:

```
Dim curr_ws As Worksheet
Set curr_ws = Worksheets("newsheet")
curr_ws.Range("B1").ColumnWidth = 342
curr_ws.Range("B").ColumnWidth = 342
curr_ws.Columns(2).ColumnWidth = 342
```

I'm trying to explicitly set the width of column B to 342 pixels if that wasn't clear.

I'm also confused as to whether this is an attribute of the `Range` object or `Columns` object since examples online are a little different than what's shown in the official documentation

Comment: The last one should be fine. It is a property of the Range object (there isn't a Columns object), but is measured in points so you have to convert to pixels.

Comment: Ah that must have been it - the points were too large since I thought it was in pixels. Thanks!

Comment: ColumnWidth and Width is different! See more about column width units and their conversion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54243836/10908769)

Comment: Looks like you are setting the ColumnWidth to 342, which with the standard font is too large and will error out. The unit is not in pixels but it is the width of one character in the normal style. Try setting the width to 255 or below and see if that fixes your issue. Here are Microsoft's docs on [ColumnWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth)

Answer (score 0):

The last one should be right. This is because the columnwidth can't be changed for one Cell. So you have to use the "Columns object". I don't know if you know that, but you could have also find that out with the help of the macro recorder. I also would give you the advice to use the intern vba sheetname, which makes the code robust against changing the sheetname.

```
Sheets("tabel1").Columns("B").ColumnWidth = 342
```

If this one doesn't work try the following:

```
Sheets("tabel1").Columns("B:B").ColumnWidth = 342
```

I hope this works as a proper solution.

Comment: Please delete your answer due to following reasons: a) the ColumnWidth can be changed on a single cell (test it!), b) referencing internal sheet names is a good idea, but then you would write `Sheet1.Columns` or maybe `tabel1.Columns`, c) the maximum usable value for ColumnWidth is 255.